# Auto Update in Electron,js with progress Bar

Tags: electron, progress-bar, auto-update

I am trying to update my electron application with auto update features provied by electorn. Auto Update is working but not with the progress bar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.